# div Wrap content or fullscreen

Tags: javascript, css

I want to know, is there a way to make a DOM element prefer being 100% of the viewport's height and width unless it's contents would overflow the viewport height or width?

I tried with this coffeescript but it ended up with some nasty recurssions

```
resizeHandled = false;
$(window).resize ->
    if(resizeHandled)
        resizeHandled = false;
        return;
    docHeight = $(document).height();
    vpHeight = $(window).height();
    if(docHeight > vpHeight)
        tallestHeight = docHeight;
    else
        tallestHeight = vpHeight;

    $("[data-fullscreen]").height(tallestHeight);
    resizeHandled = true;
```

I am in need of such thing so a fullscreen google map wont cut itself off if i rotate my device and the contents of another div on top of it overflow the viewport.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMVMD.png
This is the problem i am facing right now, id like the google map to match height with the overlaid div on top of it, it would if the container with both the map and the overlay would behave the way i am describing here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with coffeescript, but with plain javascript you could do something like this

```
var resizeHandled = false;

window.onresize = function(){

  // you may want to use document.getElementsByClassName here
  var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]; 

  if(resizeHandled || (div.clientHeight < document.documentElement.clientHeight)){
    div.style.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight + 'px';
    resizeHandled = true;
  }          
};  

window.onresize();
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa25v/)

Answer (score 0):

If the text or image contents of the div above the map are overflowing the actual div container and covering your Google Map, then you could try changing the CSS on that div element to:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

or

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```